# Negative accuracy in linear regression

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, linear-regression

My linear regression model has **negative** coefficient of determination R².

How can this happen? Any idea is helpful.

Here is my dataset:

```
year,population
1960,22151278.0
1961,22671191.0
1962,23221389.0
1963,23798430.0
1964,24397022.0
1965,25013626.0
1966,25641044.0
1967,26280132.0
1968,26944390.0
1969,27652709.0
1970,28415077.0
1971,29248643.0
1972,30140804.0
1973,31036662.0
1974,31861352.0
1975,32566854.0
1976,33128149.0
1977,33577242.0
1978,33993301.0
1979,34487799.0
1980,35141712.0
1981,35984528.0
1982,36995248.0
1983,38142674.0
1984,39374348.0
1985,40652141.0
1986,41965693.0
1987,43329231.0
1988,44757203.0
1989,46272299.0
1990,47887865.0
1991,49609969.0
1992,51423585.0
1993,53295566.0
1994,55180998.0
1995,57047908.0
1996,58883530.0
1997,60697443.0
1998,62507724.0
1999,64343013.0
2000,66224804.0
2001,68159423.0
2002,70142091.0
2003,72170584.0
2004,74239505.0
2005,76346311.0
2006,78489206.0
2007,80674348.0
2008,82916235.0
2009,85233913.0
2010,87639964.0
2011,90139927.0
2012,92726971.0
2013,95385785.0
2014,98094253.0
2015,100835458.0
2016,103603501.0
2017,106400024.0
2018,109224559.0
```

The code of the `LinearRegression` model is as follows:

```
import pandas as pd

from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

data =pd.read_csv("data.csv", header=None )

data = data.drop(0,axis=0)

X=data[0]

Y=data[1]

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split 

X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size = 0.1,shuffle =False)

lm = LinearRegression()

lm.fit(X_train.values.reshape(-1,1), Y_train.values.reshape(-1,1))

Y_pred = lm.predict(X_test.values.reshape(-1,1))

accuracy = lm.score(Y_test.values.reshape(-1,1),Y_pred)

print(accuracy)
```

```
output
-3592622948027972.5
```

Comment: in linear regression, score mean R2 and R2 can be negative, basically your model is very bad

Comment: so, any suggestion? @Reza

Comment: it could be your features are not representing the target

Comment: The problem is with the approach. You cannot random shuffle your data as it is a time series. You can take year 1961-2001 as trading and 2002-2018 as test. Trains form year to range e.g. reference_reference= 1960, all year will be (year -  reference_year).

Comment: so, any help?@Raza

Comment: X_train=data[0][:50]
X_test=data[0][50:]
Y_train=data[1][:50]
Y_test=data[1][50:]
but still -ve output

Comment: I discovered that transforming our target does the trick. See my first take below.

Comment: There is at least one error: you have fed the wrong arguments to `lm.score`.  Check the documentation.

Comment: I doubt that. I use both `func= np.log` and `inverse_func=np.exp`. So the value fed to `lm.score` are of the same unit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sckit-learn’s LinearRegression scores uses 2 score. A negative 2 means that the model fitted your data extremely bad. Since 2 compares the fit of the model with that of the null hypothesis( a horizontal straight line ), then 2 is negative when the model fits worse than a horizontal line.

```py
2 = 1 - (SUM((y - ypred)**2) / SUM((y - AVG(y))**2))
```

So if  `SUM((y - ypred)**2` is greater than `SUM((y - AVG(y))**2`, then 2 will be negative.

#### reasons and ways to correct it

*Problem 1*: You are performing a random split of time-series data. Random split will ignore the temporal dimension. 
*Solution*: Preserve time flow (See code below)

*Problem 2*: Target values are so large. 
*Solution*: Unless we use Tree-base models, you would have to do some target feature engineering to scale data in a range that models can learn.

Here is a code example. Using defaults parameters of LinearRegression and `log|exp` transformation of our target values, my attempt yield ~87% R2 score:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# we need to transform/feature engineer our target
# I will use log from numpy. The np.log and np.exp to make the value learnable

from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.compose import TransformedTargetRegressor

# your data, df

# transform year to reference

df = df.assign(ref_year = lambda x: x.year - 1960)
df.population = df.population.astype(int)

split = int(df.shape[0] *.9) #split at 90%, 10%-ish

df = df[['ref_year', 'population']]

train_df = df.iloc[:split]
test_df = df.iloc[split:]

X_train = train_df[['ref_year']]
y_train = train_df.population

X_test = test_df[['ref_year']]
y_test = test_df.population


# regressor
regressor = LinearRegression()

lr = TransformedTargetRegressor(
        regressor=regressor, 
        func=np.log, inverse_func=np.exp)

lr.fit(X_train,y_train)
print(lr.score(X_test,y_test))
```

For those interested in making it better, here is a way to read that dataset

```py
import pandas as pd
import io

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO('''year,population
1960,22151278.0 
1961,22671191.0 
1962,23221389.0 
1963,23798430.0 
1964,24397022.0 
1965,25013626.0 
1966,25641044.0 
1967,26280132.0 
1968,26944390.0 
1969,27652709.0 
1970,28415077.0 
1971,29248643.0 
1972,30140804.0 
1973,31036662.0 
1974,31861352.0 
1975,32566854.0 
1976,33128149.0 
1977,33577242.0 
1978,33993301.0 
1979,34487799.0 
1980,35141712.0 
1981,35984528.0 
1982,36995248.0 
1983,38142674.0 
1984,39374348.0 
1985,40652141.0 
1986,41965693.0 
1987,43329231.0 
1988,44757203.0 
1989,46272299.0 
1990,47887865.0 
1991,49609969.0 
1992,51423585.0 
1993,53295566.0 
1994,55180998.0
1995,57047908.0 
1996,58883530.0 
1997,60697443.0 
1998,62507724.0 
1999,64343013.0 
2000,66224804.0 
2001,68159423.0 
2002,70142091.0 
2003,72170584.0 
2004,74239505.0
2005,76346311.0
2006,78489206.0 
2007,80674348.0 
2008,82916235.0 
2009,85233913.0 
2010,87639964.0 
2011,90139927.0 
2012,92726971.0 
2013,95385785.0 
2014,98094253.0 
2015,100835458.0 
2016,103603501.0 
2017,106400024.0 
2018,109224559.0
'''))
```

*Results:*
[image]

Comment: Thanks all for your help and specially, @Prayson W. Daniel.

Comment: but i found 
`Mean Absolute Error: 56.8222474789647

Mean Squared Error: 4666.344787588366

Root Mean Squared Error: 68.31064915215171
`

Comment: Did you split your data at 90%|10%? I did not try any hyperparemter Optimization to lower the RMSE. There is room to turn it to get lower RMSE and higher R2 :)

Comment: Yes, I did split the data 90%|10%

Answer (score 5):

Here is the formula of the R² score:

[image: R2 formula]

\hat{y_i} is the predictor of the i-th observation y_i and \bar{y} is the mean of all observations.

Therefore, a negative R² means that if someone knew the mean of your `y_test` sample and always used it as a "prediction", this "prediction" would be more accurate than your model.

Moving on to your dataset (thanks to @Prayson W. Daniel for the convenient loading script), let us have a quick look at your data.

```
df.population.plot()
```

[image: Population]

It looks like a logarithmic transformation could help.

```
import numpy as np
df_log = df.copy()
df_log.population = np.log(df.population)
df_log.population.plot()
```

[image: Logarithm of the population]

Now let us perform a linear regression using OpenTURNS.

```
import openturns as ot
sam = ot.Sample(np.array(df_log)) # convert DataFrame to openturns Sample
sam.setDescription(['year', 'logarithm of the population'])
linreg = ot.LinearModelAlgorithm(sam[:, 0], sam[:, 1])
linreg.run()
linreg_result = linreg.getResult()
coeffs = linreg_result.getCoefficients()
print("Best fitting line = {} + year * {}".format(coeffs[0], coeffs[1]))
print("R2 score = {}".format(linreg_result.getRSquared()))
ot.VisualTest_DrawLinearModel(sam[:, 0], sam[:, 1], linreg_result)
```

Output:

```
Best fitting line = -38.35148311467912 + year * 0.028172928802559845
R2 score = 0.9966261033648469
```

[image: Linear regression of the logarithm of the population]

This is an almost exact fit.

**EDIT**

As suggested by @Prayson W. Daniel, here is the model fit after it is transformed back to the original scale.

```
# Get the original data in openturns Sample format
orig_sam = ot.Sample(np.array(df))
orig_sam.setDescription(df.columns)

# Compute the prediction in the original scale
predicted = ot.Sample(orig_sam) # start by copying the original data
predicted[:, 1] = np.exp(linreg_result.getMetaModel()(predicted[:, 0])) # overwrite with the predicted values
error = np.array((predicted - orig_sam)[:, 1]) # compute error
r2 = 1.0 - (error**2).mean() / df.population.var() # compute the R2 score in the original scale
print("R2 score in original scale = {}".format(r2))

# Plot the model
graph = ot.Graph("Original scale", "year", "population", True, '')
curve = ot.Curve(predicted)
graph.add(curve)
points = ot.Cloud(orig_sam)
points.setColor('red')
graph.add(points)
graph
```

Output:

```
R2 score in original scale = 0.9979032805107133
```

[image: Model fit in the original scale]

Comment: That was also my suggestion to him. :) Scikit-learn provides a good way to do that too.

Comment: Yes, of course it does! The point here is not so much the choice of library, rather than the general idea that whenever possible, you need to plot your data before trying whatever statistical tool is at your disposal.

Comment: Totally. It appears that the model fits well on transformed data, can you test the R2 with inverse(np.exp) predictions to the original scale population? I am curious if that will lower the R2 score.

Comment: Apparently, the score remains about the same in the original scale (see edit).